# flexdashboard error - pandoc: Could not fetch

Tags: css, r, pandoc, flexdashboard

I am trying include a css as described in http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#css_styles
to my flex dashboard.

```
---
title: "test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    css: https://bootswatch.com/4/litera/bootstrap.css
---
```

I am getting error:

```
pandoc: Could not fetch https://bootswatch.com/4/litera/bootstrap.css
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "bootswatch.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = []
  path                 = "/4/litera/bootstrap.css"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 (InternalException (HandshakeFailed Error_EOF))
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
In addition: There were 13 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Execution halted
```

When trying to install pandoc its giving me this:

```
> install.packages("pandoc")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘pandoc’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: update your R version

Comment: Just copy that css and save it in a local file.  Also, pandoc is not an R package, so install.packages will not work. However, pandoc comes with RStudio, so it's unlikely you'd need to install pandoc separately anyway.